# How to improve this query to show the questions and its possible answers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I developed a simple Quiz Engine web-based application similar to the one explained in the ASP.NET website. The application is very simple and it only shows multiple choice questions (with 4 possible answers only). 
I have to improve it now to show different kind of questions such as multiple choice question with single answer or multiple answers.I am struggling now with the query that will show the question with its possible choices (either two choices or 4 or 5 choices). I have the following database design:

```
Questions Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID, isCorrect
```

*(isCorrect is a flag that refers to the correct answer of that question)*

My old query was as following:

```
SELECT [QuestionID], [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [QuestionOrder] 
FROM [Question] 
WHERE ([QuizID] = @QuizID) 
ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]
```

My ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="questionDetails" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="550px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" />
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="boldtext" Width="80px" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question:" SortExpression="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer1" HeaderText="A:" SortExpression="Answer1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer2" HeaderText="B:" SortExpression="Answer2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer3" HeaderText="C:" SortExpression="Answer3" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer4" HeaderText="D:" SortExpression="Answer4" />
                        </Fields>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="generaltext" />
                    </asp:DetailsView>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT [QuestionID], [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [QuestionOrder] FROM [Question] WHERE ([QuizID] = @QuizID) ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="QuizID" Type="Int32" Name="QuizID" DefaultValue="0" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, I have to come up with a query that can show any kind of question with its possible answers or choices (either 2 or 4 or 6 choices), so **how to do that?**

NOTE: Should I have QuizID as SessionParameter in my design as shown in the ASP.NET code?

Comment: This should probably be posted at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think so. This is a new design.

Comment: The database design needs some workout.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very easy task if you try to break your problem in separate queries.

1. First query would get list of all questions
2. Second query would get list of all answers for a specific question

Something like

```
1) Select your columns from questionsTable order by questionOrder where quizId=@yourQuizId
2) Select your columns from answersTable order by answerOrder where questionId=@questionId
```

What you need to do now is

1. Use some data control(Gridview etc.) to map with all the questions
2. Drop another gridview inside a templatefield in your first gridview & a datasource
3. Bind your nested gridview on rowdatabound event(pass rowId of the current row) to the
   nested griview's datasource by using **FindControl**
4. This way it would iterate all questions with all possible answers for them

Damien.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, there is no direct link between the Questions table with Quiz Table, and there is no direct link between Answers table and Questions Table. Could you please have a look at my database design?

Comment: You only have to include 'QuizID' in questions table & 'QuestionID' in answers table & fill them with their relevant data. Without them being there how would you know which questions belong to a certain quiz & also their respective answers? Damien.

Comment: Can you specify in which table you will save the answers?

Comment: As you see in the database design, the questions will be stored in Questions Table, the answers will be stored in Answers Table. And then the QuizContent table will map the quiz with its questions and its answers. The reason that I came up with this design because I have a multiple choice question with a single or multiple answers. So I will have more than one question with a True or False as possible answers, in addition to, other similar options. Please let me know if you need further information. I am still struggling with this issue and I don't know how to implement it.